# shopengin builder template does not displayed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

After installing ShopEngine plugin I add new template to customize single product page and it works fine.
but when I comeback to builder templates page to edit the template it's look like this and can't reach the template.
how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and asked shopengine support - the solution was to turn off the TikTok plugin as there are apparently compatibility problems right now.

So: Deactivate the TikTok plugin and try again.